# Typescript and Express: are query parameters always of type string?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to use typed query parameters with typescript, express and @types/express:

```ts
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";

const app = express();

app.get('/', (request: Request<{}, {}, {}, { page: number }>, response: Response) =>
{
    response.send(`value: ${request.query.page}, type: ${typeof request.query.page}\n`);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Inside my `app.get()` method, the query properties are always of type `string`, regardless of how I defined them:

```bash
$ curl "http://localhost:3000/?page=7"
value: 7, type: string
```

I could cast the properties to the desired type, like `number` in this case. But that's the kind of thing I'm trying to avoid in the first place, by using the type system.

Is there a way to have query parameters of the type as defined in the method's signature?

Package versions used:

```
typescript 4.9.4
express: 4.18.2
@types/express: 4.17.15
```

And in `tsconfig.json`, this is enabled:

```json
"strict": true,
```